# Why is it okay to use types in a header file that weren't forward declared or included sometimes?

Tags: c++, include

Something I've noticed while attempting to learn C++ is that sometimes you only need to include headers in your .cpp file even though you've declared a variable in your header file that is of a type defined in the aforementioned include.

For example this is okay:

```
//.h file
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Tile.h"

class Grid
{
private:
    // should this be a pointer?
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tile>> _tileSet;
    Vector2 _gridDimensions;
    Vector3 _tileDimensions;

    void PopulateGrid();
    void CleanUpGrid();
public:
    Grid(Vector2 const& gridDimensions, Vector3 const& tileDimensions = { 1, 1, 1 });
    ~Grid();
};
```

```
//.cpp file
#include <memory>
#include <math.h>

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "Grid.h"

using NeighborLocation = Tile::NeighborLocation;

Grid::Grid(Vector2 const& gridDimensions, Vector3 const& tileDimensions)
{
    _gridDimensions = gridDimensions;
    _tileDimensions = tileDimensions;
    PopulateGrid();
}

Grid::~Grid()
{
    CleanUpGrid();
}

void Grid::PopulateGrid()
{
    int gridSize = _gridDimensions.x * _gridDimensions.y;
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
    {
        auto tile = std::make_shared<Tile>();
        _tileSet.push_back(tile);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
    {
        auto& tile = _tileSet[i];

        int tileXIndex = i % static_cast<int>(_gridDimensions.x);
        int tileYIndex = floor(i / _gridDimensions.x);

        int neighborIndex = 0; 
        int neighborX = tileXIndex; 
        int neighborY = tileYIndex - 1;
        if (neighborY >= 0)
        {   
            neighborIndex = neighborY * _gridDimensions.x + neighborX;
            tile->SetNeighbor(NeighborLocation::Top, _tileSet[neighborIndex]);
        }

        neighborY = tileYIndex + 1;
        if (neighborY < _gridDimensions.y)
        {
            neighborIndex = neighborY * _gridDimensions.x + neighborX;
            tile->SetNeighbor(NeighborLocation::Bottom, _tileSet[neighborIndex]);
        }

        neighborX = tileXIndex - 1;
        neighborY = tileYIndex;
        if (neighborX >= 0)
        {
            neighborIndex = tileYIndex * _gridDimensions.x + (tileXIndex - 1);
            tile->SetNeighbor(NeighborLocation::Left, _tileSet[neighborIndex]);
        }

        neighborX = tileXIndex + 1;
        if (neighborX < _gridDimensions.x)
        {
            neighborIndex = tileYIndex * _gridDimensions.x + (tileXIndex + 1);
            tile->SetNeighbor(NeighborLocation::Right, _tileSet[neighborIndex]);
        }
    }
}

void Grid::CleanUpGrid()
{
    for (auto& tile : _tileSet)
    {
        tile->CleanUp();
        tile = nullptr;
    }
}
```

but if we make this change you get the error [`SomeClass::array uses undefined class std::array<int, 4>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLGzQ.png)

```
//.h file
#pragma once

class Grid
{
private:
    // should this be a pointer?
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tile>> _tileSet;
    Vector2 _gridDimensions;
    Vector3 _tileDimensions;

    void PopulateGrid();
    void CleanUpGrid();
public:
    Grid(Vector2 const& gridDimensions, Vector3 const& tileDimensions = { 1, 1, 1 });
    ~Grid();
};
```

```
//.cpp file
#include <memory>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "Tile.h"
#include "Grid.h"

using NeighborLocation = Tile::NeighborLocation;

Grid::Grid(Vector2 const& gridDimensions, Vector3 const& tileDimensions)
{
    _gridDimensions = gridDimensions;
    _tileDimensions = tileDimensions;
    PopulateGrid();
}

Grid::~Grid()
{
    CleanUpGrid();
}

void Grid::PopulateGrid()
{
    int gridSize = _gridDimensions.x * _gridDimensions.y;
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
    {
        auto tile = std::make_shared<Tile>();
        _tileSet.push_back(tile);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
    {
        auto& tile = _tileSet[i];

        int tileXIndex = i % static_cast<int>(_gridDimensions.x);
        int tileYIndex = floor(i / _gridDimensions.x);

        int neighborIndex = 0; 
        int neighborX = tileXIndex; 
        int neighborY = tileYIndex - 1;
        if (neighborY >= 0)
        {   
            neighborIndex = neighborY * _gridDimensions.x + neighborX;
            tile->SetNeighbor(NeighborLocation::Top, _tileSet[neighborIndex]);
        }

        neighborY = tileYIndex + 1;
        if (neighborY < _gridDimensions.y)
        {
            neighborIndex = neighborY * _gridDimensions.x + neighborX;
            tile->SetNeighbor(NeighborLocation::Bottom, _tileSet[neighborIndex]);
        }

        neighborX = tileXIndex - 1;
        neighborY = tileYIndex;
        if (neighborX >= 0)
        {
            neighborIndex = tileYIndex * _gridDimensions.x + (tileXIndex - 1);
            tile->SetNeighbor(NeighborLocation::Left, _tileSet[neighborIndex]);
        }

        neighborX = tileXIndex + 1;
        if (neighborX < _gridDimensions.x)
        {
            neighborIndex = tileYIndex * _gridDimensions.x + (tileXIndex + 1);
            tile->SetNeighbor(NeighborLocation::Right, _tileSet[neighborIndex]);
        }
    }
}

void Grid::CleanUpGrid()
{
    for (auto& tile : _tileSet)
    {
        tile->CleanUp();
        tile = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Notice the only differences between the two files are that I have moved `#include <vector>` and `#include "Tile.h"` from header to cpp; I have also removed reference to the DirectX math library which is a standard part of the DirectX API. The first compiles; the second does not.

This error also happens when using any other types that you've defined.
Why is this?

Comment: I figured you'd like to know. I'm using VS 2017 as my IDE so this is with Microsoft's compiler.

Comment: I suggest you provide real (and small and complete) samples of code that illustrate whatever points you're trying to make.     Don't rely on non-standard headers such as `<DirectXMath.h>` since they aren't known to everyone.   The first example that you say "is okay" is not actually valid C++.    So you're forcing people to guess what your actual question is.   If you don't address all that, your post is simply unclear, and will attract close votes.

Comment: Alright I will post the FULL header and cpp files in this example.

HOWEVER, the portions of the code that I have highlighted here are just simplified versions of the source code and actual problem I am talking about

Comment: @Peter I have updated the question to your specification.

Comment: We need a [mre]. That means it's both a complete program that can be used to **reproduce** the problem **as is** and that it contains the **minimal** amount of code necessary. In other words, don't include code that isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Peter I've updated this question to have a photo of the error if we just move the include of Tile.h.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang I included the minimum amount of code you needed to reproduce it initially and got yelled at for not including enough code

Comment: The code you initially posted couldn't be used to reproduce the problem. The first example which you say is okay won't compile because `std::shared_ptr` wasn't declared. The basis of your question isn't clear since in both of your examples the code won't compile due to the use of an undeclared type.

Comment: Are you talking about being able to use `std::shared_ptr` without including the `<memory>` header? Standard library headers sometimes include each other but that's not guaranteed by the C++ standard.

Comment: do you have `#include "Grid.h"` somewhere else in your code base which doesn't include `"Tile.h"`? knowing which cpp file was reporting the error would be helpful

Comment: There is still a lot of unneeded code that is making it difficult to see what your points are. I would suggest aiming for very simple code. Forget grids, and just have `class A` with no methods. Possibly no data either, unless a data field demonstrates/triggers the error. Simple and abstract. No frills.

Comment: The code you are showing now is not a [repro] either. It is neither minimal nor complete. It is missing the contents of `Tile.h` making it non-complete and it is non-minimal because it includes irrelevant member functions such as `PopulateGrid` etc. Also please don't post images of code. Copy-paste the error message into the question in plain-text. Please don't interpret this as being "*yelled at*". Without a [repro] questions are simply impossible to answer or answer appropriately. Forming a [repro] does in itself often help one to understand what the underlying issue is.

Comment: @kmdreko Grid.h is the file that was showing the error. thats why I used it as an example.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang the origin code I posted would have compiled because I ran a test with almost that exact code. the only difference I ran in my test was the addition of constructor and destructor code in my cpp file.